# Google Webmaster returning 404 on dynamic pages

Tags: php, dynamic, google-search-console

I've created a site that redirects all 404 to index. The index php checks the subdirs name, sees if it exists in the db, and shows the content appropriately.

This works perfectly fine. However google does not index these pages, and Google Webmaster returns 404 for all of them.

my structure is as such:

```
mydomain.com/TheData/
```

The htaccess code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Since **'TheData'** is in my db, it would return proper content.

I have tried specifying each in the sitemap and in .htaccess RewriteRule'n each but google webmaster always returns 404.

How can I fix this? How do sites (like wordpress) make non-existent subdirectories look real to google?

Thank you.

Comment: re-create robots.txt once

Comment: I have created a new robots.txt and submitted it to Webmaster. I've also specified header('Content-Type: text/html'); prior to my include statements that render the pages, and still google is saying 404.

Comment: Update: I've also tried setting : header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); prior to rendering the content, and google still returns 404 in testing. I'm not sure what avenue to try next.

Comment: The answer/fix for me was to add these lines to htacces

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . /